# I can not set bootstrap carousel interval in angularjs

Tags: carousel

I can't get my head around of the Angularjs version carousel. I am just simply using the bootstrap version. The intervals I tried are 1s or 10s, but it doesn't seem to change. It always change picture around something like 5s?. My html code is like below:

```
<!-- Carousel================================================== -->
            <div id="myCarousel_whatdowedo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel_whatdowedo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel_whatdowedo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <!-- <li data-target="#myCarousel_whatdowedo" data-slide-to="2"></li> -->
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img class="first-slide " ng-src="{{c.image1}}" alt="First slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img class="second-slide" ng-src="{{c.image2}}" alt="Second slide">
                    </div>
                    <!-- <div class="item">
          <img class="second-slide" ng-src="{{data.whyus_page1.image3}}" alt="Second slide">
        </div> -->

                </div>
                <!-- here change bootstrap a link to spans to avoid angularjs router interuption -->
                <span class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel_whatdowedo" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </span>
                <span class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel_whatdowedo" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </span>
            </div>
            <!-- /.carousel -->
```

then in the controller. I simply have the following in the controller. but the interval only changes around 4 seconds.

```
        $('.carousel').carousel({
          interval: 1000
        });
```

below is the full controller.

```
.controller('WhatdowedoBodyController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$anchorScroll','UserService',
    function($scope, $http,  $location, $anchorScroll, UserService) {
        $http.get('json/whatdowedo.json').success(function(data) {
            $scope.data = data;
        });  

        $('.carousel').carousel({
          interval: 1000
        });

    }


])
```

could someone help me?

Comment: i should not use $('.carousel') in my project no jquery code should be there is there any other alternative like angular.element('.carousel')